# How to split a numpy array to 2d array based on postive/neagtive changes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 1D array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,  1,  3, -2, -1,  2,  0,  2,  1,  1, -3, -1,  2])
```

I want split it into another two-dimensional array, based on changes in positive and negative values of array's elements(0 is placed in the range of positive values). But the original order of elements should be maintained.

The desired result is:

```
new_arr = [[1, 1, 3], [-2, -1], [2, 0, 2, 1, 1], [-3, -1], [2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), [`nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
np.array_split(arr, np.nonzero(np.diff(arr>=0))[0]+1)
```

Ouptut:

```
[array([1, 1, 3]),
 array([-2, -1]),
 array([2, 0, 2, 1, 1]),
 array([-3, -1]),
 array([2])]
```

Intermediates:

```
# arr>0
[ True  True  True False False  True False  True  True  True False False  True]

# np.diff(arr>=0)
[False False  True False  True False False False False  True False  True]

# np.nonzero(np.diff(arr>=0))[0]+1
[ 3  5 10 12]
```

And for lists as output:

```
out = list(map(list, np.array_split(arr, np.nonzero(np.diff(arr>=0))[0]+1)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 3], [-2, -1], [2, 0, 2, 1, 1], [-3, -1], [2]]
```

Or using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(arr, key=lambda x: x>=0)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [3, -2], [-1, 2, 0, 2, 1], [1, -3], [-1, 2]]
```

##### comparison of approaches

[image: comparison array split numpy itertools groupby]

Comment: Can those "array's "be removed from the new results?

Comment: @Sun do you mean `out = list(map(list, np.array_split(arr, np.nonzero(np.diff(arr>=0))[0]+1)))`?

Comment: But if you want a list you can also use `itertools.groupby`

Comment: That's what I want, I prefer np method to itertools.

Comment: @Sun yes, it's a bit faster for large arrays. I'll add a comparison

Answer (score 2):

If you want standard python lists, you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

arr = np.array([1, 1, 3, -2, -1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, -3, -1, 2])

out = []
for _, g in groupby(arr, lambda k: k < 0):
    out.append(list(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 1, 3], [-2, -1], [2, 0, 2, 1, 1], [-3, -1], [2]]
```

Comment: :D I just added the same. I agree if python lists are desired this might be more straightforward

Comment: Also a nice algorithm, but I like np native method, itertools maybe a bit of slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following logic:

```
def split_array(arr):
    new_arr = []
    subarr = []
    
    for elem in arr:
        if (elem >= 0 and subarr and subarr[-1] < 0) or (elem < 0 and subarr and subarr[-1] >= 0):
            new_arr.append(subarr)
            subarr = []
        subarr.append(elem)
    
    if subarr:
        new_arr.append(subarr)
    
    return new_arr
```